# Filter & display results by name or competition, list from MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

Technically I can almost imagine how it should be, but example with my data is more then welcome.

Query code is:

```
      $results = $mysqli->query("SELECT tulemus_id, v6istlus.aeg, v6istlus.nimi, 
riik.lyhend, riik.pilt2, riik.pilt, riik.nimi_est, 
v6istlus.riik_id, v6istlus.vlink, 
liige_v.Eesnimi, liige_v.Perekonnanimi, 
liige_v.wplink, klass.lyhend, tulemus.koht, osalejaid, punktid 
        FROM tulemus 
        INNER JOIN liige_v on tulemus.liige_id = liige_v.liige_id
        INNER JOIN v6istlus on tulemus.v6istlus_id = v6istlus.v6istlus_id
        INNER JOIN klass on tulemus.klass_id = klass.klass_id
        INNER JOIN riik on v6istlus.riik_id = riik.riik_id
WHERE liige_v.liige_id = '$namefilter'

        ");
```

Table is :

```
print '<table class="mytable7">';
echo "<tr><th>V&otilde;istlus </th><th>Aeg </th><th>Riik </th><th>Liige </th><th>Klass </th><th>Koht</th><th>OK*</th><th>Punktid</th></tr>";

while($row = $results->fetch_array()) {
    print '<tr>';
    echo '<td><a href="'.$row["vlink"].'" target="_blank">'.$row["nimi"].'</a></td>';
    print '<td>'.$row["aeg"].'</td>';
    echo "<td><img src='/kliendid/baltosport/upload/flag/".$row['pilt2']."'width='30' height='20' '></td>";
    echo '<td><a href="'.$row["wplink"].'" target="_blank">'.$row["Eesnimi"].' '.$row["Perekonnanimi"].' </a></td>';
    print '<td>'.$row["lyhend"].'</td>';
    print '<td>'.$row["koht"].'</td>';
    print '<td>'.$row["osalejaid"].'</td>';
    print '<td>'.$row["punktid"].'</td>';
    print '</tr>';
}   
print '</table>';

// Frees the memory associated with a result
$results->free();

echo "<tr> OK* Osalejaid klassis </tr>";
print '<br/>';
```

Visual:
[link](http://yx.ee/kliendid/baltosport/kuva/tulemus_liige.php)
[image]

Now I want to add dropdown to select by Name (Liige) or by competition .. and when group by Name then nice to have points SUM (punktid) as well ;)

Comment: Pls format your query for readability

Answer (score 0):

You need to add WHERE clause in your query if you want the such filter

Comment: Yes I understand, that I need use WHERE in query, but.. I'm "green" in that

Comment: what do you mean by "green" ?? Just Add, 
WHERE table_name.column_name = 'your_value'

Comment: Need to add droptown /select list where I can choose competition Name let's say Lauri Reppo .. And after that displaying only Lauri's reults and SUM the points

Comment: Yes I understand when I modifi my query to '...INNER JOIN riik on v6istlus.riik_id = riik.riik_id
WHERE liige_v.liige_id = '48''
the page displayng [picture](https://www.dropbox.com/s/w3p9raovwx1l7ll/Screenshot%202015-04-30%2010.55.19.png?dl=0) .. but I need select the name with dropdown and Sum points will by nice